# Center three div containers next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want three divs to be centered in the mid. In the end it should look like this[image]

now my problem. In my css I used the float keyword but it seems this does not work for sure. The divs still split up.

As you can see in the following code example the containers are getting weird.

Would be awesome if someone could help me out there!

```css
#selectionElementContainer {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#selectionElementLeft {
  float: left;
}

#selectionElementCenter {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#selectionElementRight {
  float: right;
}

.selectionElementImage {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementHeader {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #333f4b;
}

.selectionElementText {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #4c545c;
}

.selectionElementLinkContainer {
  cursor: default;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementBtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1bbee7;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.selectionElementBtn:hover {
  color: #a4d662;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
    <div id="selectionElementContainer">
      <div id="selectionElementLeft">
        <div class="selectionElementImage">
          <img src="bild">
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementHeader">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementText">
          Text
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementLink">
          <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="selectionElementCenter">
        <div class="selectionElementImage">
          <img src="bild">
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementHeader">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementText">
          Text
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementLink">
          <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="selectionElementRight">
        <div class="selectionElementImage">
          <img src="bild">
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementHeader">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementText">
          Text
        </div>
        <div class="selectionElementLinkContainer">
          <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in this case the parent container is flexed and the children as well with a direction of column for your specific case. You can target nested elements with the pseudo element `nth-child(n)` for instance `.flex-child:nth-child(2) h2 {color: green;}` will make the second `<h2>` green [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zboLsrzc/2/)

```css
#flex-parent{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-child img{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.flex-child a{
  margin-bottom: 20px; /*So you can have space when the screen resize*/
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>              
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use floats, float all items to the left. Your center element was taking up the whole width of the container element and pushing the third element down.

Beyond that it looks like you're over-engineering things a little bit. See my example below on how you can simplify your markup and CSS and make it a bit more semantic.

```css
.selection {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.selection img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="selections">

  <div class="selection">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/fc0">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="selection">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="selection">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/fc0">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If you want to get a bit more modern with your approach, use `flexbox`.

```css
#selections {
  display: flex;
}

.selection {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.selection img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="selections">

  <div class="selection">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/fc0">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="selection">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="selection">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400/fc0">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Float them all left and make the width 33% (roughly a third). I also made the text center aligned as I thought it looked better but feel free to omit if you prefer.

```css
#selectionElementContainer {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#selectionElementLeft, #selectionElementCenter,#selectionElementRight {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}

.selectionElementImage {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementHeader {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #333f4b;
}

.selectionElementText {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #4c545c;
}

.selectionElementLinkContainer {
  cursor: default;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementBtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1bbee7;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.selectionElementBtn:hover {
  color: #a4d662;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="selectionElementContainer">
  <div id="selectionElementLeft">
    <div class="selectionElementImage">
      <img src="bild">
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementHeader">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementText">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementLink">
      <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="selectionElementCenter">
    <div class="selectionElementImage">
      <img src="bild">
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementHeader">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementText">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementLink">
      <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="selectionElementRight">
    <div class="selectionElementImage">
      <img src="bild">
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementHeader">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementText">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementLinkContainer">
      <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your existing CSS and just change the order of your divs so that it's left, right, center. This way the left and right divs will be positioned to the left and right sides respectively, and the center div will float up between them.

```css
#selectionElementContainer {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow:auto;
}

#selectionElementLeft {
  float: left;
}

#selectionElementCenter {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#selectionElementRight {
  float: right;
}

.selectionElementImage {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementHeader {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #333f4b;
}

.selectionElementText {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #4c545c;
}

.selectionElementLinkContainer {
  cursor: default;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementBtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1bbee7;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.selectionElementBtn:hover {
  color: #a4d662;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="selectionElementContainer">
  <div id="selectionElementLeft">
    <div class="selectionElementImage">
      <img src="bild">
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementHeader">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementText">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementLink">
      <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="selectionElementRight">
    <div class="selectionElementImage">
      <img src="bild">
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementHeader">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementText">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementLinkContainer">
      <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="selectionElementCenter">
    <div class="selectionElementImage">
      <img src="bild">
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementHeader">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementText">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="selectionElementLink">
      <button class="selectionElementBtn">Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I also added `overflow:auto` to your container div so that the container actually contains the floated divs.

Comment: Spineless downvoter care to grow a pair and explain the problem with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Easy explanation, instead using float which you may need to be controlling the parent size and applying an empty div, you can use **display: inline-block** as you may see at **selectionElement class**

You can use something like this:

```
#selectionElementContainer {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.selectionElement {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  border: #f0f thin solid;
}

.selectionElementImage {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementHeader {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #333f4b;
}

.selectionElementText {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #4c545c;
}

.selectionElementLinkContainer {
  cursor: default;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selectionElementBtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1bbee7;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.selectionElementBtn:hover {
  color: #a4d662;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: `inline-block` will leave whitespace around the element which might cause reflow issues if corrective measures are not taken.

Comment: @hungerstar nowadays, if you use something like normalize.css it won't happen and besides teach a better way using "inline-block, flexbox, grid-css" is better than apply something for IE6/7

Comment: That's not true, `normalize.css` won't fix the whitespace. Especially if you were to use percentage widths that add up to 100%, [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/cye826wr/) - third element in first example wraps due to whitespace even though `normalize.css` is included. If the widths add up to less that 100% then the whitespace _might not_ be an issue.

Comment: @hungerstar yeah, you are right, it may add `margin-right: -4px` to fix this issue, which is weird because I never came across but good to know

Comment: Using fixed margin like that isn't the best. The whitespace will very in size based on the font size. Stick with floats or flexbox. There are other ways to fix it but they're all _"hack-ish"_ - like setting the font size to zero on parent element and then restoring font size on the inline block elements or using HTML comment tags. Just too much work and fidgeting when floats and especially flexbox are simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e10oj1gm/) and see if it answered the question. Just need to float all left.

```
float: left;
width:30%;
```